# Does using only immutable data types make a Java program thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, immutability

Is it true that if I only use immutable data type, my Java program would be thread safe?

Any other factors will affect the thread safety?

****Would appreciate if can provide an example. Thanks!**
**

Comment: @Erick Robertson - An example that solves every problem ever! :)

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood - Would appreciate if can provide that example. Thanks!

Comment: @Erick:  If he can pull it off, that's likely worth all the food ever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thread safety is about protecting shared data and immutable objects are protected as they are read only. Well apart from when you create them but creating a object is thread safe.

It's worth saying that designing a large application that ONLY uses immutable objects to achieve thread safety would be difficult.

It's a complicated subject and I would recommend you reading [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1285167736&sr=8-1)
which is a very good place to start.

Comment: Not difficult per se, but a solid understanding of FP is necessary and using a functional language makes it much less painful.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to create an object in a way that isn't thread safe. Starting a thread from the constructor is a good way to break thread safety, for example, if the new thread has a reference to the object that you haven't finished constructing.

Comment: @Bill Michell - Yes, and this is something that is covered by Java Concurrency in Practice. You have to be aware of how to use this in the consturctor.

Comment: Immutable objects won't save you from incorrect behavior -- just _some_ (not all) of the difficult to diagnose problems that can happen with threads.

Answer (score 3):

It is true.  The problem is that it's a pretty serious limitation to place on your application to only use immutable data types.  You can't have any persistent objects with state which exist across threads.

I don't understand why you'd want to do it, but that doesn't make it any less true.

Details and example: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29

Answer (score 2):

If every single variable is immutable (never changed once assigned) you would indeed have a trivially thread-safe program.

[Functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) environments takes advantage of this.

However, it is pretty difficult to do pure functional programming in a language not designed for it from the ground up.

A trivial example of something you can't do in a pure functional program is use a loop, as you can't increment a counter. You have to use recursive functions instead to achieve the same effect.

If you are just straying into the world of thread safety and concurrency, I'd heartily recommend the book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/), by Goetz. It is written for Java, but actually the issues it talks about are relevant in other languages too, even if the solutions to those issues may be different.

Comment: As the question is asked, you could increment a loop variable which existed only within the local function.  This would be completely thread-safe as the variable would only exist on the stack for that thread.

Comment: Actually, the question asks about a program that only uses immutable data types. There *are* ways to write thread safe java programs with mutable variables, and JCIP talks about most of them. But I believe I did answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Immutability allows for safety against certain things that can go wrong with multi-threaded cases. Specifically, it means that the properties of an object visible to one thread cannot be changed by another thread while that first thread is using it (since **nothing** can change it, then clearly another thread can't).

Of course, this only works as far as that object goes. If a mutable reference to the object is also shared, then some cases of cross-thread bugs can happen by something putting a new object there (but not all, since it may not matter if a thread works on an object that has already been replaced, but then again that may be crucial).

In all, immutability should be considered one of the ways that you can ensure thread-safety, but neither the sole way nor necessarily sufficient in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Although immutable objects are a help with thread safety, you may find "local variables" and "synchronize" more practical for real world progamming.

Answer (score 0):

Any program where no mutable aspect of program state is accessed by more than one thread will be trivally thread-safe, as each thread may as well be its own separate program.  Useful multi-threading, however, generally requires interaction between threads, which implies the existence of some mutable shared state.

The key to safe and efficient multi-threading is to incorporate mutability at the right "design level".  Ideally, each aspect of program state should be representable by one immutably-rooted(*), mutable reference to an object whose observable state is immutable.  Only one thread at a time may try to change the state represented by a particular mutable reference.  Efficient multi-threading requires that the "mutable layer" in a program's state be low enough that different threads can use different parts of it.  For example, if one has an immutable `AllCustomers` data structure and two threads simultaneously attempted to change different customers, each would generate a version of the `AllCustomers` data structure which included its own changes, but not that of the other thread.  No good.  If `AllCustomers` were a mutable array of `CustomerState` objects, however, it would be possible for one thread to be working on `AllCustomers[4]` while another was working on `AllCustomers[9]`, without interference.

(*) The rooted path must exist when the aspect of state becomes relevant, and must not change while the access is relevant.  For example, one could design an `AddOnlyList<thing>` which hold a `thing[][]` called `Arr` that was initialized to size 32.  When the first thing is added, `Arr[0]` would be initialized, using `CompareExchange`, to an array of 16 `thing`.  The next 15 things would go in that array.  When the 17th thing is added, `Arr[1]` would be initialized using `CompareExchange` to an array of size 32 (which would hold the new item and the 31 items after it).  When the 49th thing is added, `Arr[2]` would be initialized for 64 items.  Note that while `thing` itself and the arrays contained thereby would not be totally immutable, only the very first access to any element would be a write, and once `Arr[x][y]` holds a reference to something, it would continue to do so as long as `Arr` exists.