# How to make this Threadsafe

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been reading a lot about threading yet I am not sure of the right way to handle this situation. Lets say I have a utility class that references an object. The utility class does work on the object and it can be called from multiple threads

```
  class Utility{
     Foo xx;
     public Utility(Foo xx){
         this.xx = xx;
     }

    public void doWork(){
       x.action();
    }
  }
```

Now if I have two threads that will will be accessing the utility class and calling doWork() where xx will always refers to the same object, how can I make it thread safe?

EDIT: There are 2 instances of the utility class ( one per thread) but the same referenced xx object. See Edit:

```
public class ThreadSafety {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Foo xx = new Foo();
        Utility util1 =  new Utility(xx); 
        Utility util2 =  new Utility(xx); 
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(util1) , "t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(util2) , "t2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();

    }

}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    Utility util;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        util.doWork();
    }


    private void MyRunnable (Utility util) {
        this.util = util;
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that if the doWork method does not change the state of the Foo instance (and particularly if Foo is immutable), then no synchronization is required.

Comment: +1 @JamesWatson who gave the only answer that told you to make `xx` private.  No point in providing synchronized methods to operate on data that other methods can access without synchronization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Utility{
  private final Foo xx;

  public Utility(Foo xx){
    this.xx = xx;
  }

  public void doWork() {
    // ensures only one thread can be calling action
    synchronized(xx) {
      xx.action();
    }
  }
}
```

A few changes below:

1. Make `xx` `final` and `private`.  Making it `private` enforces controls on how `xx` can be accessed.
2. `synchronize` on `xx` before calling `doWork`.  You can put `synchronized` on the method declaration but I prefer to be explicit about what object you are locking on.  Note that this doesn't "synchronize xx".  It simply uses `xx` as the lock.  You must use synchronized blocks with the same monitor object everywhere you are accessing potentially dangerous code blocks.

Comment: Will this work even if multiple instances of Utility are created but referencing same Foo? It is in my Edit of the question

Comment: Actually yes.  I didn't consider this initially but this version **will** work with multiple instances of Utility referencing the same Foo instance.  Using `synchronized` on the method **will not** work in that case.  The reason is that `synchronized` on a object level method is the same as saying `synchronized(this){//method body}` where `this` is the Utility instance.  In that situation the threads would lock on different (`Utility`) objects even if the Foo instance is the same which will **not** prevent them from running `doWork` on the same Foo at the same time.

Comment: So if I understand correct. Putting the synchronized on the method itself will not work because it is multiple instances. but if I put synchronized on xx like you did in your answer then it will work because your locking the referenced  object.. Correct?

Comment: Sort of.  You can lock on any object.  For example you might come across something like `private static Object LOCK = new Object();` which can puzzling until you see it used in a `synchronize` block as the lock object.  Think of it like a "talking stick" in a tribal meeting where only the person holding the stick is allowed to talk.  Locking on the object has no effect on the object itself, it's just what the threads use to keep track of whether another thread is in the critical section and whether they can enter.

Comment: One more important note, when choosing objects for locks, make sure you choose something that is aligned with your threading needs.  For example, if you are locking on a private variable that might be reassigned, you can have issues.  Never lock on an object that will be reassigned within the synchronized block unless you want see behaviors that are very hard to reason about.

Answer (score 3):

Java has a `synchronized` keyword that you can use in this situation.

```
public synchronized void doWork()
```

**Reading**

- There's a full explanation of the keyword in the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: Please see edit to the question, will your way still apply as it will be two different instances?

Comment: @Snake Don't completely change the question after you've already received answers - the reason should be obvious. Also no it won't.

Comment: I didn't  completely change it. I made it clearer because it seems there was an assumption that it is the same utility class. I actually just clarified that it is more than one utility class. Sorry!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `synchronized` key word.

```
 public synchronized void doWork(){
       x.action();
    }
```

This will make the method thread safe. More on synchronized methods on [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

**With the updated question:**
Use static method as synchronized, then the lock will be on the class not on individual object.

Comment: Please see edit to the question, will your way still apply as it will be two different instances?

Comment: And the answer is no. If it is util method may be you want it to be as a `static`? Then it will work.

Comment: Using `static` here is overkill because it will prevent **all** instances of `Foo` from being accessed through any instance of Utility via `doWork`.  Using an explicit `synchronize` block on the `Foo` instance should solve the problem at the right level.  I never use the syntactic sugar of `synchronized` on method declarations.  I believe it's the main reason there is so much confusion around synchronization in Java.

Comment: You are right. Like I said in previous comment, if it is meant to be util method then there's no need for instance of `Foo` inside Utilty class. Just pass the `Foo` in `doWork()` method.

Answer (score 2):

And here is an alternative advise:

> Do ***not*** use `synchronized`.

Code that uses `synchronized` tends to be complex, buggy, and tends to perform poorly. Worst of all, it tends to suffer from race conditions. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).)

The inconvenient thing about race conditions is that there exists no kind of test that will catch them. Unit Testing certainly won't. You might *think* that stress-testing will catch them, but in fact it will not necessarily catch them either, because they can be incredibly elusive: you may have a race condition which manifests itself on average every million seconds of continuous runtime; this means that in order to witness this race condition happening even once, you would have to be running your software day and night for 11 days straight, which of course you will not do; however, once your software is deployed to a million customers out there, the laws of statistics say that one random customer will be experiencing it roughly every second.

Java was introduced in the early nineties, so it had to support the predominant-at-the-time mechanism for sharing data across threads, which was synchronization. Thus, Java has had the `synchronized` keyword since version 1. This inevitably lead to situations where application programmers who used to be coding in COBOL in their previous job were now writing code in Java and trying to make use of `volatile` and `synchronized`; needless to say, there was much weeping and wailing and gnashing of teeth. Synchronization is very difficult; Entire books have been written on the subject; the tiniest mistake is catastrophic, you cannot avoid tiny mistakes unless you are an expert, and few people on the planet are considered experts.

In the decades that followed since then, the Software Industry has been realizing the importance of Software Testing and therefore the importance of Testability. For this reason, synchronization has been falling out of grace and being abandoned. Using the `synchronized` keyword nowadays is indicative of a certain disconnection from the best practices of our times.

So, ***do not*** use the `synchronized` keyword; this means: ***do not*** share state between your threads; instead, follow the modern ***Share-Nothing*** approach. This approach can be summarized as follows:

Create an **immutable** class which you will call `Message` to communicate between your threads, and use a `BlockingQueue` (from package `java.util.concurrent`) in which other threads store messages intended to be processed by your main thread. Then, in your main thread, just keep popping messages from the queue and processing them.  If the main thread needs to communicate results to another thread, then create another queue for that thread. Simple, elegant, testable, foolproof.

The implementation of `BlockingQueue` does internally make use of synchronization techniques, but it has been written by people who knew what they were doing, and it has been thoroughly tested, so it is known to work. That single data structure is the only place in your entire system that should contain synchronization.

Comment: Interesting... I don't have too many multithreading to do. It is only that one object that I am worried will be accessed by multiple threads. However, any link you recommend to this Immutable solution and BlockingQueue? If there is a straight forward example on the web then I could use that (and accept this answer :))

Comment: There's a lot of good information in this answer but I have to disagree that it's simpler to use queues and workers.  For someone trying to get their head around multithreading, working with synchronization in Java is like a guided lesson in the basics.  If you have low contention, it's tends to be much faster than using the newer more advanced concurrency options.  However, with lots of threads, it's very difficult to keep all the threads working and make it correct with synchronization.  For simple stuff like making sure objects are created once etc. it's fine.

Comment: I do not know of any notably good sample off the top of my head.  So, I did a google search, looked at the results real quick, and picked for you the one which seems better than the rest: http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3645111/Java-5s-BlockingQueue.htm

Comment: 1 for the link and the info.. Will come helpful in future .. Thank you so much but I agree with  James

Answer (score 2):

If you have changing data, consider using immutable objects, not just simply slapping on a synchronized keyword.

Read

- [This stackoverflow question on immutable data and thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770539/does-using-only-immutable-data-types-make-a-java-program-thread-safe)
- [Oracle's documentation on immutability](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html)